# Should I include research stays in my CV?

Tags: application, cv, europe

During my PhD I was invited three times by two researchers to stay and do research in their lab, one week at a time. I'm now a postdoc and applying to tenured jobs in Europe (yay). Should I include these stays in my CV for these job applications?

To be fair most of the deadlines have already gone for these applications. Someone just mentioned to me that they did that so I'd like more opinions on this. To be even more fair I'm pretty sure I will still need the advice next year. (Some more research stays are coming up, also.)

Comment: Are you able to find example CVs of other people in your area? Often these are online. I find this to be the best guideline.

Comment: What sort of research can you get done in only a week?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai A lot, if you focus... Although I work in a theoretical field, so "doing research" is writing on a board or a paper. When you meet with someone 5-6 hours every day for a week, things can go quickly.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think following the norm always produces the best results. The nature of academic job searches make want to be (or at least look) *better* than my competitors, not indistinguishable...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, listing them would add some more value to the CV.

This is how I would list it in my CV under a section called **Research Visits**.

Research Visits

- Visiting researcher, ABC Laboratory, University of Alphabets (Duration: January 01 -- January 09, 2018; Supervisor/Collaborator: Professor A. BCDEG)
- Visiting researcher, ABC Laboratory, University of Alphabets (Duration: January 23 -- January 30, 2018; Supervisor/Collaborator: Professor A. BCDEG)

Comment: Doesn't the title "Visiting research scholar" sound a bit pompous...? Besides I don't really want to list the researchers as "supervisors", they were my collaborators during these visits, I wrote papers with them... They weren't the ones telling me what to do. But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would, of course, include them if they enhance my chances of getting the job. You should simply judge how relevant these are to the job you are applying to. If these stays are relevant, do not hesitate to include them. Otherwise, you may skip them.
Good luck!

Comment: With all due respect, that's not really an answer. You're basically telling me "do it if you think it can help". Well, that's my question: can it help?