# Benefits of including short and/or long-term visits abroad on my CV?

Tags: phd, cv, europe

I am in my first year of a theoretical physics PhD in the UK and I'm coming to the end of a week abroad at another institution where some collaborators of mine work. The purpose of the visit is to make some quick progress on a specific project, and I applied for (and was awarded) a small grant from an EU funding body to pay for the visit.

The answers to a closely related question, ["Should I include research stays in my CV?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105019/should-i-include-research-stays-in-my-cv), suggest that such stays should be included on a CV.

I see [my CV](https://nataliebhogg.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/cv_nbh.pdf) as essentially a record of my professional activities, and this visit therefore falls within that scope, but I wonder if, due to the short nature of the visit, it would be seen as padding. I already have a modest section of my CV devoted to grants, awards and prizes, where I also list the specific monetary amounts I received, so is it wiser simply to list the funding and not mention the visit it was used for?

Further to this, I intend to apply for more funding soon which will allow me to visit the same institution plus another in another country for much longer (possibly up to six months). If I am successful in this regard, should I include the visit, the funding or both on my CV?

**Question:**  What are the possible benefits/drawbacks of including a visit or/and its funding on a CV?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I include research stays in my CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105019/should-i-include-research-stays-in-my-cv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any drawbacks adding your grants and visits in CV, but it will surely increase the weightage of your CV in this competitive world. I have been a Travel Grant Reviewer since last 5 years to select suitable candidates to attend the meetings/conferences. My experiences give the following merits to add them in CV.

- Grants/Awards/Prizes proves your ability to be considered in top researchers.
- Visits abroad proves your ability to work in different environments/places and with different peoples.
- Listing your conferences and presentation details proves your ability/interest to present your work in the international forum.

So all the points have their own meaning to define your potential. If you don't mention them, then how do you think that you will be evaluated properly?